# Terminology / reference request: Calculus of variations with constraints on the family of curves

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, calculus-of-variations, functional-calculus, variational-analysis

I am interested in variational problems of the following form:
$$
\max J(y)
\quad\text{such that}\quad
y\in C,
$$

where $J(y)=\int_0^b f(x,y,y')\,dx$ is a functional and $C$ is a specified family of smooth curves. As an example, $C$ could be the family of all straight lines: $C=\{y\in C^1[0,b] : y(x) = xu \,\exists\, u\in\mathbb{R}^d\}$. More generally, $C$ could specify bounds on the curvature of $y$, the length of $y$, etc.

"Traditional" calculus of variations can be used to solve problems in which $C$ is the family of all curves satisfying certain boundary conditions (e.g. $y(0)=x_1$, $y(b)=x_2$), but I am not familiar with a more general theory for general families $C$. (One well-known extension is the variable endpoint problem, but I am interested in even more general families as above.)

So, I have two questions:

1. Is there a name for these kind of constraints?
2. Are there any good references for these types of problems?

Answer (score 1):

The family of all straight lines is finite dimensional, and your problem reduces to a finite dimensional calculus problem for them.

Anyway, for more generality, here are some things you may want to search for:

If you *fix* the length, you have an "isoperimetric constraint", usually solved by Lagrange multipliers. If you only specify bounds, you will get some type of "variational inequality" or "obstacle problem".